# How do I limit the number of characters processed in Power automat?

Tags: power-automate, maxlength, powerapps-formula

If an email meets the criteria defined in the flow "When a new email arrives", the record is entered from the email into the Google Sheet table. However, if the email contains more than 1000 characters, this process will not be completed and will end as an Error. I need to limit the processing of a maximum of the first 300 characters and ignore the rest.
My flow is here:
[image]

I tried to insert this operation but it didn't work:
substring(outputs('Html_to_text'), 0, 300)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"?   Also, you could have a condition check the length of this string.